# Implementing Vue SFC with Webpack (no Vue CLI)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I've recently switched to Webpack and have all my JS and CSS running perfectly through it now. Here's the relevant piece of webpack.config.js:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            },
            {loader: 'import-glob-loader'}
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader},
            {loader: 'css-loader'},
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: [
                        require('autoprefixer')
                    ]
                }
            },
            {loader: 'sass-loader'},
            {loader: 'import-glob-loader'}
        ]
    }
]
```

I have Vue included from a CDN and with this setup I can do the following no problem:

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            title: 'Title',
            description: 'Description'
        };
    },
    methods: {
        created: function () {
            console.log('Created');
        }
    },
    template: '<section id="test-component"><h2>{{ title }}</h2>{{ description }}</section>'
});

new Vue({el: '#app'});
```

And in my HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <test-component></test-component>
</div>
```

I'd now like to use Vue single file components instead, and reading the docs it tells me to simply run .vue files through vue-loader, so I changed my rules to the following:

```
rules: [
    // NOTE: This is new
    {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            },
            {loader: 'import-glob-loader'}
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader},
            {loader: 'css-loader'},
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: [
                        require('autoprefixer')
                    ]
                }
            },
            // NOTE: This is new too, but commented because it throws errors
        //  {loader: 'vue-style-loader'},
            {loader: 'sass-loader'},
            {loader: 'import-glob-loader'}
        ]
    }
]
```

With that in place my .vue files are picked up and added to dist/main.js so it seems to be working (as long as I don't include a `<style>` element in the Vue file in which case it fails), but now `new Vue({el: '#app'})` does absolutely nothing. Checking the DOM the `<test-component>` is still in there and not rendered by Vue at all.

If I also try to enable `vue-style-loader` the build fails entirely saying:

```
(1:4) Unknown word

    > 1 | // style-loader: Adds some css to the DOM by adding a <style> tag
        |    ^
      2 | 
      3 | // load the styles
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Progress. Thanks to Daniel my `<style>` now works as long as it has `lang="scss"` set. This is because my webpack config only has rules for `scss` files and not `css` files.

I've also figured out the reason the `<test-component>` won't render is because I never actually register it, simply including the `.vue`-file is not enough for it to be registered obviously.

The problem I'm having now is trying to glob import all my `.vue`-files as an array of components. If I do this it works fine:

```
import TestComponent from "./test-component.vue";
import AnotherComponent from "./another-component.vue";

document.querySelectorAll('[data-vue]').forEach(el => {
    new Vue({
        el: el, 
        components: {
            'test-component': TestComponent, 
            'another-component': AnotherComponent
        }
    });
});
```

But I'd like to be able to do this some how:

```
import components from "./**/*.vue";

document.querySelectorAll('[data-vue]').forEach(el => {
    new Vue({
        el: el, 
        components: components
    });
});
```

Using `import-glob-loader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply importing the `vue` files is not enough for them to be available for use. You also have to register them with Vue.

So, this is wrong:

```
import 'component.vue';

new Vue({el: '#app'});
```

This is right:

```
import component from 'component.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app', 
    components: {
        'component': component
    }
});
```

That takes care of making them usable.

The reason the `<style>` elements don't work is because I don't have a webpack rule for `CSS` files - only for `SCSS` files. Thanks to @Daniel for pointing out that I need `<style lang="scss">`.

`vue-style-loader` is only needed to inject styles into the DOM as `<style>` elements which I don't actually use (I use `mini-css-extract-plugin` to create `css`-files) also according to the docs:

> However, since this is included as a dependency and used by default in vue-loader, in most cases you don't need to configure this loader yourself.

Will create a separate question regarding the glob import.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `<style lang="scss">` in your SFC

You can also try deleting the package-lock and node_modules folder and do a clean install. Sometimes that can resolve an issue if the dependencies are not using compatible versions.

---

### Update

To import using glob style imports you may need to use `import-glob`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob

You can also achieve similar result using global component registration. This is documented well in the official docs at:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components

Comment: I'm not using any style at all so far. And when I tried using it I tried plain CSS - no SASS. The problem I'm having is that my component doesn't render at all. Not sure why I'd need to delete node_modules and package-lock?

Comment: Just in case the dependency versions are not playing nice. This looks a bit like a _"works fine on my machine ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"_ issue

Comment: Ah ok I see. I did realize one thing however, I'm never actually registering my SFC anywhere like I am with the Vue.component example. I'm just importing the vue file and nothing more. So that's probably my issue. Will get back once near computer.

Comment: Ok so a couple of things: 1) Using `lang="scss"` actually makes my `<style>`s work so thanks for that (I understand this is because I only have a webpack rule for `scss` files and not for `css`) and 2) The reason the component doesn't render is because it's never registered. I've updated my question with my new problems. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am using `import-glob-loader` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader) already, the problem is that I can't import all `vue`-files and then pass them to `new Vue()` because there doesn't seem to be a way to import them all into an array. `webpack-import-glob-loader` does seem to support this however so I will check it out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-import-glob-loader

Comment: I think I'll create a new question regarding the glob import. The only real problem I had here was that I never registered my components and that is now solved.